# How to initialize a character or string array using for loop in c++?

Tags: c++

I want to make a 2 dimensional array of 13 rows and 6 columns all initialized with character X. to do so I'm doing this.

```
char myseats[13][5];
for (int i; i < 13; i++)
{
    myseats[i] = { 'X' };
    for (int j; j < 5; j++)
        {
            myseats[j] = {'X'};
        }
    }
}
```

however this gives me a error and the array wont initialize with X, same is the case with string. How can I achieve my purpose can anyone please help me?

Comment: You have forgotten to initialize the variable i,j. It will first take the value of (random) that it's address previously store. That will may cross your size limit of array definition. Initialize i and j in their respective loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
char myseats[13][5];
for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
{
   for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
   {
      myseats[i][j] = 'X';
   }
}
```

First, the `i` and `j` where not initialized in the loop. You need to define at what index you want them to start.

Second, the correct way to access a two dimensional array is with the syntax `array[row_index][column_index] = 'your_desired_value_here'`.

Comment: `i` and `j` are uninitialized at this point.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to access fields of two dimensional array, you should use `myseats[i][j]` (first you specify row, then the column). Also, your for loops are written incorrectly. When you initialize any variable in the body of for loop, you should assign its value (otherwise `i` and `j` can have any value that can be saved in `int`). Your code should look like that:

```
char myseats[13][5];
for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        myseats[i][j] = {'X'};
    }
}
```